# Flutter - Can't save all json data to Iterable List from api response EDIT: ( Can't Fetch Data from iterable List)

Tags: json, api, flutter, dart

I've an api that return some data. I only need to fetch dish data from the api. The issue is while I'm getting data from the api response, the first dish data is only saving to `iteratable list`.

**EDIT**

**I can't fetch the data from Iterable List**

the api is like below

```
  [
  {

    "restaurant_name": "Cafe",
    "restaurant_image": "http://restaurants.unicomerp.net/images/Restaurant/1010000001.jpg",
    "table_id": "1",
    "table_name": "Table 01",
    "branch_name": "Cafe",
    "nexturl": "http://snapittapp.snapitt.net/api/menu/10/?org=1010000001&branch_id=1000000001&limit=10&offset=20&lang=en",
    "table_menu_list": [
      {
        "menu_category": "Salads and Soup",
        "menu_category_id": "11",
        "menu_category_image": "http://restaurants.unicomerp.net/images/Restaurant/Item/ItemGroup_11.jpg",
        "nexturl": "http://snapittapp.snapitt.net/api/menu/20/?org=1010000001&branch_id=1000000001&menuCat=11&limit=10&offset=20&lang=en",
        "category_dishes": [
          {
            "dish_id": "100000001",
            "dish_name": "Spinach Salad",
            "dish_price": 7.95,
            "dish_image": "http://restaurants.unicomerp.net//images/Restaurant/1010000001/Item/Items/100000001.jpg",
            "dish_currency": "SAR",
            "dish_calories": 15,
            "dish_description": "Fresh spinach, mushrooms, and hard-boiled egg served with warm bacon vinaigrette",
            "dish_Availability": true,
            "dish_Type": 2,
            "nexturl": "http://snapittapp.snapitt.net/api/menu/30/?org=1010000001&branch_id=1000000001&menuItem=100000001&limit=10&offset=20&lang=en",
            "addonCat": [
              {
                "addon_category": "Spicy/Non-Spicy",
                "addon_category_id": "104",
                "addon_selection": 0,
                "nexturl": "http://snapittapp.snapitt.net/api/menu/40/?org=1010000001&branch_id=1000000001&menuItem=100000001&menuAddonCat=104&menuAddonselc=0&limit=10&offset=20&lang=en",
                "addons": [
                  {
                    "dish_id": "100000032",
                    "dish_name": "Non Spicy",
                    "dish_price": 25,
                    "dish_image": "http://restaurants.unicomerp.net/images/Restaurant/Item/Item_100000025.jpg",
                    "dish_currency": "SAR",
                    "dish_calories": 15,
                    "dish_description": "Non Spicy",
                    "dish_Availability": true,
                    "dish_Type": 1
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "addon_category": "Add On",
                "addon_category_id": "101",
                "addon_selection": 1,
                "nexturl": "http://snapittapp.snapitt.net/api/menu/40/?org=1010000001&branch_id=1000000001&menuItem=100000001&menuAddonCat=101&menuAddonselc=1&limit=10&offset=20&lang=en",
                "addons": [
                  {
                    "dish_id": "100000020",
                    "dish_name": "fried onions",
                    "dish_price": 15,
                    "dish_image": "http://restaurants.unicomerp.net/images/Restaurant/Item/Item_100000020.jpg",
                    "dish_currency": "SAR",
                    "dish_calories": 10,
                    "dish_description": "fried onions",
                    "dish_Availability": true,
                    "dish_Type": 2
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dish_id": "100000003",
            "dish_name": "Traditional New England Seafood Chowder",
            "dish_price": 12,
            "dish_image": "http://restaurants.unicomerp.net/images/Restaurant/1010000001/Item/Items/100000003.jpg",
            "dish_currency": "SAR",
            "dish_calories": 30,
            "dish_description": "with clams, scallops, and shrimp,",
            "dish_Availability": true,
            "dish_Type": 1,
            "nexturl": "http://snapittapp.snapitt.net/api/menu/30/?org=1010000001&branch_id=1000000001&menuItem=100000003&limit=10&offset=20&lang=en",
            "addonCat": []
          },
          {
            "dish_id": "100000004",
            "dish_name": "Salad Bar Soup",
            "dish_price": 5,
            "dish_image": "http://restaurants.unicomerp.net/images/Restaurant/1010000001/Item/Items/100000004.jpg",
            "dish_currency": "SAR",
            "dish_calories": 30,
            "dish_description": "Flour Mixed with fresh green leafy vegetables",
            "dish_Availability": true,
            "dish_Type": 2,
            "nexturl": "http://snapittapp.snapitt.net/api/menu/30/?org=1010000001&branch_id=1000000001&menuItem=100000004&limit=10&offset=20&lang=en",
            "addonCat": []
          },
          {
            "dish_id": "100000005",
            "dish_name": "chicken-soup",
            "dish_price": 14.89,
            "dish_image": "http://restaurants.unicomerp.net/images/Restaurant/1010000001/Item/Items/100000005.jpg",

            "dish_id": "100000029",
            "dish_name": "Tacos",
            "dish_price": 25,
            "dish_image": "http://restaurants.unicomerp.net/images/Restaurant/Item/Item_100000029.jpg",
            "dish_currency": "SAR",
            "dish_calories": 225,
            "dish_description": "Mexican Street Tacos",
            "dish_Availability": true,
            "dish_Type": 3,
            "nexturl": "http://snapittapp.snapitt.net/api/menu/30/?org=1010000001&branch_id=1000000001&menuItem=100000029&limit=10&offset=20&lang=en",
            "addonCat": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

there is a data category called **addonCat** in the api, I need this to be ignored and go on to the next dish when fetching data from the response.

**api_model.dart** this where I'm fetching the data from response of api

```
class CategoryDishes {
  final String dishId;
  final String dishName;
  final double dishPrice;
  final String dishImage;
  final String dishCurrency;
  final double dishCalories;
  final String dishDescription;
  final bool dishAvailability;
  final double dishType;
  final String nexturl;

  //final List<AddonCat> _addonCat;

  CategoryDishes(
      {this.dishId,
      this.dishName,
      this.dishPrice,
      this.dishImage,
      this.dishCurrency,
      this.dishCalories,
      this.dishDescription,
      this.dishAvailability,
      this.dishType,
      this.nexturl});

  factory CategoryDishes.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return CategoryDishes(
        dishId: json['dish_id'],
        dishName: json['dish_name'],
        dishPrice: json['dish_price'].toDouble(),
        dishImage:
            json['dish_image'] ?? Constants.FOOD_PLACEHOLDER_IMAGE_ASSET_URL,
        dishCurrency: json['dish_currency'],
        dishCalories: json['dish_calories'].toDouble(),
        dishDescription: json['dish_description'],
        dishAvailability: json['dish_Availability'],
        dishType: json['dish_Type'].toDouble(),
        nexturl: json['nexturl']);
  }

  static Resource<List<CategoryDishes>> get all {
    return Resource(
        url: Constants.FOOD_API_URL,
        parse: (response) {
          final result = json.decode(response.body.toString());
          //  print(response);
          Iterable list = result[0]['table_menu_list'][0]['category_dishes'];
          debugPrint("=========== Dish_List ==============\n" + list.toString());
          debugPrint("====================================");
          return list.map((model) => CategoryDishes.fromJson(model)).toList();
        });
  }
}
```

**web.service.dart**

```
class Resource<T> {
  final String url;
  T Function(Response response) parse;

  Resource({this.url, this.parse});
}

class Webservice {
  Future<T> load<T>(Resource<T> resource) async {
    final response = await http.get(resource.url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
     // debugPrint("------D------>\n" + response.body);
      return resource.parse(response);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load data!');
    }
  }
}
```

**main.dart**

https://pastebin.com/NuDKYCCD

Now I can save the data to the Iterable List, but can't fetch data from the list to the card elements. Above `main.dart` is the place where I'm fetching the data.

How to achieve this?

**EDIT**

I'm only able to get the first part of the `dishlist` in the api, after the first category there is many of the dishes are available, I need to fetch all of the dishlist and display it to the corresponding tabs, refer above api link to know how the api is.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here that you only do it for the first item in result and in table_menu_list

```dart
  static Resource<List<CategoryDishes>> get all {
    return Resource(
        url: Constants.FOOD_API_URL,
        parse: (response) {
          final result = json.decode(response.body.toString());
          //  print(response);
          Iterable list = result[0]['table_menu_list'][0]['category_dishes'];
          debugPrint("=========== Dish_List ==============\n" + list.toString());
          debugPrint("====================================");
          return list.map((model) => CategoryDishes.fromJson(model)).toList();
        });
  }
```

The parse function I would do it like this

```dart
final result = json.decode(response.body.toString());
          //  print(response);
List<CategoryDishes> list = []
List.from(result).forEach((item) =>
List.from(item['table_menu_list']).forEach((menuItem) => 
  List.from(menuItem['category_dishes']).forEach((dish) => 
   list.add(CategoryDishes.fromJson(dish))
)
)
);
debugPrint("=========== Dish_List ==============\n" + list.toString());
debugPrint("====================================");
return list;
```

If you don't want to have repeated dishes in the list  (dishes with the same id), you could use a map

```dart
final result = json.decode(response.body.toString());
          //  print(response);
Map<String, CategoryDishes> map = {}
List.from(result).forEach((item) =>
List.from(item['table_menu_list']).forEach((menuItem) => 
  List.from(menuItem['category_dishes']).forEach((dish) => 
   map[dish['dish_id']] = CategoryDishes.fromJson(dish);
)
)
);
return map.values.toList();
```

Comment: Thanku. Now I'm getting all dishes data in my screen.

Answer (score 4):

Its actually saving the data. But its not printing on the console when using `debugPrint`.

You have to give `wrapWidth` in `debugPrint`, so that you can see full response stored in a variable.

```
debugPrint(
  "=========== Dish_List ==============\n" + list.toString(),
  wrapWidth: 1000,
);
debugPrint("====================================");
```

I think this is the problem you are facing.

You can also do pretty-print to make it understandable

```
debugPrint(
  "=========== Dish_List ==============",
);
JsonEncoder encoder = new JsonEncoder.withIndent('  ');
debugPrint('${encoder.convert(list)}', wrapWidth: 1000);
debugPrint("====================================");
```

Comment: @AllwiN Glad that helped. I also updated my answer with pretty print. you can check it.

Comment: Still when I'm trying to fetch the data to my card elements nothing shows? what am I doing wrong. this the `main.dart` https://pastebin.com/NuDKYCCD, here I'm fetching the value for the card elements.

Comment: @AllwiN I will try to find the problem. But you may want to change the question or create a new post. So that other people can also help you.

Comment: @AllwiN I am not sure what the problem is. But you may refer this code [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/vijayaragavangkf/2e4f085bb74a863e018043905022f034)

Comment: There is an issue I'm facing, That I couldn't fetch all data from `api` response. Only the first array named `dish` only I can fetch from the response. How to get all the dishes from the api? the code remains same as I posted in the question.

Comment: @AllwiN if possible share some screenshots pls. Thank you.

Comment: I updated the question with an EDIT, please see the api, Already I accepted your answer, as only it is a part of the answer I needed.

Comment: Because you only using first dish category (0th index). `Iterable list = result[0]['table_menu_list'][0]['category_dishes'];` you may need to create another PODO class like `DishMenu`.

Comment: suggest me a link or something improve this issue, I already have a generate JSON class. but don't know how to do what u meant

Comment: I updated the [git](https://gist.github.com/vijayaragavangkf/2e4f085bb74a863e018043905022f034). Pls read the code and understand it. Then modify it as you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

Listing all the dishes

```
Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 10, 5, 10),
            child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount:  apiResponse[0]['table_menu_list'][0]['category_dishes'].length,
              itemBuilder:(cc,ind){
                return ListTile(
                title:Text(apiResponse[0]['table_menu_list'][0]['category_dishes'][ind]['dish_name'])
                  //use other properties as your requirement
                );
              }
            ))
```

Getting date from network. I used local assignment of data ! Replace with your own method

```
void assignData(){
    apiResponse = [
  {

    "restaurant_name": "Cafe",
    "restaurant_image": "http://restaurants.unicomerp.net/images/Restaurant/1010000001.jpg",
    "table_id": "1",
    "table_name": "Table 01",
    "branch_name": "Cafe",
    "nexturl": "http://snapittapp.snapitt.net/api/menu/10/?org=1010000001&branch_id=1000000001&limit=10&offset=20&lang=en",
    "table_menu_list": [
      {
        "menu_category": "Salads and Soup",
        "menu_category_id": "11",
        "menu_category_image": "http://restaurants.unicomerp.net/images/Restaurant/Item/ItemGroup_11.jpg",
        "nexturl": "http://snapittapp.snapitt.net/api/menu/20/?org=1010000001&branch_id=1000000001&menuCat=11&limit=10&offset=20&lang=en",
        "category_dishes": [
          {
            "dish_id": "100000001",
            "dish_name": "Spinach Salad",
            "dish_price": 7.95,
            "dish_image": "http://restaurants.unicomerp.net//images/Restaurant/1010000001/Item/Items/100000001.jpg",
            "dish_currency": "SAR",
            "dish_calories": 15,
            "dish_description": "Fresh spinach, mushrooms, and hard-boiled egg served with warm bacon vinaigrette",
            "dish_Availability": true,
            "dish_Type": 2,
            "nexturl": "http://snapittapp.snapitt.net/api/menu/30/?org=1010000001&branch_id=1000000001&menuItem=100000001&limit=10&offset=20&lang=en",
            "addonCat": [
              {
                "addon_category": "Spicy/Non-Spicy",
                "addon_category_id": "104",
                "addon_selection": 0,
                "nexturl": "http://snapittapp.snapitt.net/api/menu/40/?org=1010000001&branch_id=1000000001&menuItem=100000001&menuAddonCat=104&menuAddonselc=0&limit=10&offset=20&lang=en",
                "addons": [
                  {
                    "dish_id": "100000032",
                    "dish_name": "Non Spicy",
                    "dish_price": 25,
                    "dish_image": "http://restaurants.unicomerp.net/images/Restaurant/Item/Item_100000025.jpg",
                    "dish_currency": "SAR",
                    "dish_calories": 15,
                    "dish_description": "Non Spicy",
                    "dish_Availability": true,
                    "dish_Type": 1
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "addon_category": "Add On",
                "addon_category_id": "101",
                "addon_selection": 1,
                "nexturl": "http://snapittapp.snapitt.net/api/menu/40/?org=1010000001&branch_id=1000000001&menuItem=100000001&menuAddonCat=101&menuAddonselc=1&limit=10&offset=20&lang=en",
                "addons": [
                  {
                    "dish_id": "100000020",
                    "dish_name": "fried onions",
                    "dish_price": 15,
                    "dish_image": "http://restaurants.unicomerp.net/images/Restaurant/Item/Item_100000020.jpg",
                    "dish_currency": "SAR",
                    "dish_calories": 10,
                    "dish_description": "fried onions",
                    "dish_Availability": true,
                    "dish_Type": 2
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dish_id": "100000003",
            "dish_name": "Traditional New England Seafood Chowder",
            "dish_price": 12,
            "dish_image": "http://restaurants.unicomerp.net/images/Restaurant/1010000001/Item/Items/100000003.jpg",
            "dish_currency": "SAR",
            "dish_calories": 30,
            "dish_description": "with clams, scallops, and shrimp,",
            "dish_Availability": true,
            "dish_Type": 1,
            "nexturl": "http://snapittapp.snapitt.net/api/menu/30/?org=1010000001&branch_id=1000000001&menuItem=100000003&limit=10&offset=20&lang=en",
            "addonCat": []
          },
          {
            "dish_id": "100000004",
            "dish_name": "Salad Bar Soup",
            "dish_price": 5,
            "dish_image": "http://restaurants.unicomerp.net/images/Restaurant/1010000001/Item/Items/100000004.jpg",
            "dish_currency": "SAR",
            "dish_calories": 30,
            "dish_description": "Flour Mixed with fresh green leafy vegetables",
            "dish_Availability": true,
            "dish_Type": 2,
            "nexturl": "http://snapittapp.snapitt.net/api/menu/30/?org=1010000001&branch_id=1000000001&menuItem=100000004&limit=10&offset=20&lang=en",
            "addonCat": []
          },
          {
            "dish_id": "100000005",
            "dish_name": "chicken-soup",
            "dish_price": 14.89,
            "dish_image": "http://restaurants.unicomerp.net/images/Restaurant/1010000001/Item/Items/100000005.jpg",

            "dish_id": "100000029",
            "dish_name": "Tacos",
            "dish_price": 25,
            "dish_image": "http://restaurants.unicomerp.net/images/Restaurant/Item/Item_100000029.jpg",
            "dish_currency": "SAR",
            "dish_calories": 225,
            "dish_description": "Mexican Street Tacos",
            "dish_Availability": true,
            "dish_Type": 3,
            "nexturl": "http://snapittapp.snapitt.net/api/menu/30/?org=1010000001&branch_id=1000000001&menuItem=100000029&limit=10&offset=20&lang=en",
            "addonCat": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
  }
}
```

Screenshot
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you bud!!.. let me try this.

Comment: cc and ind ---> context and index??

Comment: This is not working. the thing is the data is not storing to the iterable list.

Comment: Use List<Map> instead of iterable

Comment: How to use List<Map> api_model.dart?

Comment: while i'm trying to use, i got an error like `[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>'` in console.

Comment: Then use List instead of List<Map>

Comment: List tmpList = apiResponse[0]['table_menu_list'][0]['category_dishes']; then get by index

Comment: Now I'm using List, when printing List to the console nothing shows, also I tried to fetch data for the text and images, really not showing anything, I declared List as global so I can access it to both classes... please evaluate this code https://pastebin.com/MRp0FBeh